# Typedef use in terms of char arrays

Tags: c, arrays, typedef

Little confused on the use of typedef and then using the alias to create a char array.

```
#define BIGVALUE 50
typedef char TEST[BIGVALUE];
TEST array[10];
```

Does array become a pointer to a 10 by 50 array?
Is this what an array of array's appears like?
Thanks.

Comment: No, arrays are not pointers.  However, your code is equivalent to `char array[10][50]`.

Comment: AH, how could I be so stupid. Relatively new to C. I originally thought it would hold/store a pointer value. But the answer below makes sense.

Answer (score 7):

`array` is an array of 10 TESTs

and

`TEST` is an array of 50 chars

hence `array` is an array of 10 array of 50 char, which equals to `char[10][50]`